# Array ArrayList python equivalent

Tags: java, python, arrays, arraylist

I just looked up **array** and **arrayList**

and found out that an **array** is fixed length and can't be changed while an **arraylist** can be changed and is variable in length

my question is:

is **array** == **tuple** in python?

and is **arraylist** == **list** in python?

and if they aren't what are array and arraylist's python equivalent?

Comment: @Tim I did. I asked to clarify whether I am understanding it right or not.

I know what a **list** and **tuple** is in python and I'm trying to learn java and they behave similarly. that's why I asked the question to clarify if my understanding of it is right or not

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ArrayList` in java and `list` in python are both dynamic arrays. They both have O(1) average indexing time and O(1) average adding an element to the end time.

`Array` in java is **not** `tuple` in python. While it is true that you cannot add elements to both data structures. Python `tuple` does not support assignment, that is you cannot reassign individual elements in a `tuple`, while you can in java `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

- Java's ArrayList is similar to Python's List.
- Nicer than Array for adding and removing items.
- Java's Array has fixed length like you
  mentioned.
- Not sure what its equivalent in Python would be.

Comment: so an array is immutable?

Comment: Java arrays are not immutable, merely fixed length. There is no direct equivalent in Python; Python types with fixed lengths are usually immutable (because there is no significant benefit to making mutable types have fixed length).